# How to correctly collect related data in Yii2 REST API?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I have two ActiveRecord models: Category & Product with many-to-many relation (via ProductCategory model) & I'm trying to build REST API that will search & return products with `name LIKE '%term%'` grouped by categories.

My ApiController:

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use api\modules\v1\models\Category;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use Yii;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 50;

    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];

    public function actionSearchProductsByTerm()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->get('term')) {
            return new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => Category::find()
                    ->with([
                        'products' => function ($query) {
                            /** @var $query yii\db\ActiveQuery */
                            $query->andWhere(['like', 'name', Yii::$app->request->get('term')]);
                        }
                    ]),
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                ],
            ]);
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Missing term parameter in request');
        }
    }
}
```

But when I request api.my-site.loc/v1/searchProductsByTerm?term=iphone&expand=products I see following result:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Apple technics",
        "url": null,
        "products": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Apple smartphones",
        "url": null,
        "products": []
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Apple tablets",
        "url": null,
        "products": []
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Apple notebooks",
        "url": null,
        "products": []
      }
    ],
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://api.my-site.loc/v1/searchProductsByTerm?term=iphone&expand=products&page=1&per-page=50"
      },
      "first": {
        "href": "http://api.my-site.loc/v1/searchProductsByTerm?term=iphone&expand=products&page=1&per-page=50"
      },
      "last": {
        "href": "http://api.my-site.loc/v1/searchProductsByTerm?term=iphone&expand=products&page=1&per-page=50"
      }
    },
    "_meta": {
      "totalCount": 4,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "currentPage": 1,
      "perPage": 50
    }
  }
}
```

Question: why is a list of all categories on the site displayed, and not just those that contain products with `name LIKE '%iphone%'`? At the same time, the array of products is empty everywhere for some reason. What did I miss? And another question: is it possible to somehow return an array of products by default, so as not to specify `expand=products` every time (because for this API method this is redundant, since the search will always be performed by product attributes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently fetching all the categories and then adding the products. If you want to remove the categories that don't have matching products you should change to an inner join.

```php
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Category::find()
        ->innerJoinWith([
            'products' => function ($query) {
                return $query->where(['like', 'name', Yii::$app->request->get('term')]);
            }
        ])
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => self::ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
    ],
]);
```

---

To return the products list by default you could add the products to the default fields. This will however always fetch the products when `toArray()` is called on a Category model. So you might want to be careful.

```php
// In the Category model
public function fields() {
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields[] = 'products';
    return $fields;
}
```

You could also add the `products` as an expand to the get parameters by default for this specific request. Needs a bit of cleaning perhaps, but could be something like:

```php
    $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams();
    $currentExpand = explode(',', $queryParams['expand']);
    $currentExpand[] = 'products';
    $queryParams['expand'] = implode(',', $currentExpand);
    Yii::$app->request->setQueryParams($queryParams);
```

Comment: Your query for `ActiveDataProvider` would look for categories with name that matches the term. But OP wanted to look for categories that contain products with matching name and those products. You can either use inner query or join to look for categories like that. You would need to combine it with `with()` with callback to limit what products are loaded for found categories.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I read the question wrong.. I've updated the answer

Comment: I've changed my code by adding `products p` alias as array key in `innerJoinWith` method & modified query to the following: `$query->andWhere(['like', 'p.name', Yii::$app->request->get('term')]);` but now I have an empty `"items": []` array in response result (while the database contains exactly the products that match the search condition).

Comment: I think an empty `items` array makes sense, because in your situation all the product arrays were also empty. So after the adjustment 'items without products' are removed from the results, which are all items in this case. You might want to check why the query isn't returning any results. Perhaps the query isn't correct or maybe the data isn't in the db? If you want to check the query it might help to see the generated sql by outputting: $query->createCommand()->getRawSql()

Comment: The problem was in the case-sensitive search: I changed the condition to ```$query->andWhere(['ilike', 'p.name', Yii::$app->request->get('term')]);``` and everything worked! Thank you for your help!